# Elasticsearch Painless script: Strip off date component from a date field and want to use time component only

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-painless

I am an ES noob.
Started exploring ES recently.

I have an index called Products.
Each product has createdAT dateTime field.
I want to write a query that will return results based on 2 conditions.

1. Consider products that were created between 1st September 2023 and 10th September 2023.
2. Return only the products that were created between 6 AM to 10 AM or between 4 PM to 10 PM on all the days mentioned in condition 1.

To realize the 2nd condition, I was trying to use the painless script.

```
var searchResponse = await _client.SearchAsync<ProductModel>(s => s.Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(m =>
                m.DateRange(r => r.Field(f => f.CreatedDateTime)
                        .GreaterThanOrEquals(startDateTz) //1st Sep 2023
                        .LessThanOrEquals(endDateTz) //10th Sep 2023
                ))
            .Filter(f => f.Script(sn =>
                sn.Name("hour_filter")
                    .Script(sc => sc
                        .Source(
                            "if(doc.createdDateTime.value.getHour() >= params.s1 && doc.createdDateTime.value.getHour() <= params.e1) return true;if (params.containsKey(s2) && params.containsKey(e2)) { if(doc.createdDateTime.value.getHour() >= params.s2 && doc.createdDateTime.value.getHour() <= params.e2) return true;else  return false;")
                        .Params(AddParams(adjustedStartAndEndTimes))))))) 
//adjustedStartAndEndTimes has the time spans s1 - 6 AM, e1 - 10 AM, s2 - 4 PM, e2 - 10 PM.
```

This is not working. Any pointers in realizing this would be really helpful.